# how can i import an object file of 400 mb into blender ,it freezes "" and if any hotkeys are pressed it stops responding

Tags: modeling, export

I did a model in rhino for 50 Mb and i exported as a wavefront obj file and while importing that into the blender it was 400 Mb and blender froze for 5-6 mins and stopped responding.
1.is there any problem on my side?
2.if not, the procedure what'll be it?
3.how to effectively solve it
my Pc specs: 1060 ti 6 Gb graphics,16 Gb ram,i9 8th gen processor SSD 512 Gb

Comment: There is a known issue with large .obj imports in blender, and it's being addressed. You might try using the better obj importer branch which you can find on graphicall.It's offline at the moment, but it should be back up before too long. Or you might try compiling it yourself if you're computer savvy.

Comment: try Instant Meshes to reduce the polycount and size of your rhino model and try again.  
here is a small video https://www.blendernation.com/2015/11/16/instant-meshes-a-free-qaud-based-autoretopology-program/